# retrieving an item from array always returns -1

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get pull a value from an array based on the index and I can't get it to work for some reason. Keeps returning -1

```
$alphabet =  [char[]]([char]'a'..[char]'z')
$AZ = 'A'..'Z

##Option 1
[array]::indexof($AZ, 2)

##Option 2
$AZ.IndexOf( 2 )
```

both of these options return -1

I should say I tried following this article.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/find-the-index-number-of-a-value-in-a-powershell-array/

Comment: You want `$AZ[2]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps you identify the problem:

```
PS /> [char[]]$alphabet = 'a'..'z'
PS /> [array]::IndexOf($alphabet,'f') #=> Returns -1
PS /> [array]::IndexOf($alphabet,[char]'f') #=> Returns 5
PS /> $alphabet.IndexOf('f') #=> Returns -1
PS /> $alphabet.IndexOf([char]'f') #=> Returns 5

PS /> ([char]'f').Equals([string]'f') #=> Returns false, here is your hint
```

Comment: That definitely was it!  Thanks for the teaching moment as well!